# How do I get the latest call logs in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-cursor, telephonymanager, calllog

I have a code that works below. But I can't limit it. I just want to get the last 20 call logs.
But that's how I see all-time search logs.

**It should only be the last call logs and I only need to see 20 pieces. Any help, I'd appreciate it.**

> My Code;

```
private void getCallLogs() {

        ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int totalCall = 1;
        if (c != null) {
            totalCall = c.getCount();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < totalCall; j++) {

                    String callDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                    String phNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                    String callDuration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
                    Date dateFormat= new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                    String callDayTimes = String.valueOf(dateFormat);
                    String direction = null;

                    switch (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)))) {
                        case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX:
                            direction = "OUTGOING";
                            break;
                        case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT:
                            direction = "INGOING";
                            break;
                        case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX:
                            direction = "MISSED";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(this, phNumber + direction + callDuration + callDayTimes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your `for` loop is making use of `totalCall` why not just change that to 20 ?

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. @a_local_nobody

Comment: `totalCall = 20` If this doesn't work, show us what you tried and explain what happened.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I didn't realize this simple thing because of a little mistake. And now it works as I want thanks a lot !!!

Comment: It works yes. But of what essence is the for loop? :/ Its more like doing nothing or are my missing something?

Comment: That's all, man. I just wanted to be able to see 20 records and send them to the database and see them through the admin panel, and all right. :P @GiddyNaya

Comment: I am only saying there is no need of the for loop. though your code works now removing it would make no difference as it even adds extra over load on the app.

Comment: You can add an edit to your post or reply your answer with the update for other surfers of similar problem to know how it was fixed.

Comment: Okey dear, thank for helping. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add this permission in your manifest file.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
> ```

Add this function in your Activity file and call it in oncreate function.

```js
 public void getCallLogs() {            
        int flag=1;
        title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Call Logs</b>"));
        deviceDetails.setText(Html.fromHtml(""));
        StringBuilder callLogs = new StringBuilder();

        ArrayList<String> calllogsBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
        calllogsBuffer.clear();
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }
            calllogsBuffer.add("\nPhone Number: " + phNumber + " \nCall Type: "
                    + dir + " \nCall Date: " + callDayTime
                    + " \nCall duration in sec : " + callDuration + "\n");

        }
        managedCursor.close();
}
```

To call this function, add this to your oncreate function in your Activity.

> getCallLogs();

Comment: Oh man. I asked this question 6 months ago and I had a solution. I added the answer above. Still, your answer looks good and is similar to mine. I'm sure it will work and I mark this as the answer. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Replace managedquery with getContentResolver().query. The reason for this is managedquery is deprecated and shows "Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed" error.

Answer (score 3):

Here we can create an integer with the for loop that we have already created and set a limit here.

**I'm sorry about my bad English.**

> Function;

```
private void getCallLogs() {

    ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    int totalCall = 1;

    if (c != null) {
        totalCall = 10; // intenger call log limit

        if (c.moveToLast()) { //starts pulling logs from last - you can use moveToFirst() for first logs
            for (int j = 0; j < totalCall; j++) {


                String phNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                String callDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                String callDuration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
                Date dateFormat= new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                String callDayTimes = String.valueOf(dateFormat);

                String direction = null;
                switch (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)))) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        direction = "OUTGOING";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        direction = "INCOMING";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        direction = "MISSED";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                c.moveToPrevious(); // if you used moveToFirst() for first logs, you should this line to moveToNext

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phNumber + callDuration + callDayTimes + direction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // you can use strings in this line 

            }
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 comments: (1) the default sort order of Calls is "date DESC" so to get the last 10 calls you should query the *first* 10 cursor rows.
(2) if there are less the 10 calls in the call-log this code might crash, the loop should be `while (c.moveToNext() && j < totalCalls)` and then increment `j` manually

Comment: @marmor Not sure if you read that right, but if I do that of changing to `moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext()`, Lollipop 5.1 OnePlus X will get me June logs... Only with `moveToLast()` and `moveToPrevious()` does it get me today's logs. Though, the while thing is a good idea. But not a while alone, as it will miss the last log. Must be a do-while, being the while statement what you said.

Comment: @DADi590 you're getting the older calls first because of the sort order, see my comment #1 - you need to specify sort date DESC to make the last calls appear first.